# How to manipulate a Textfield in the Browser using a Java Programm?

Tags: java, javascript, automation, firefox-addon

Hi my Question is one kind of an automatization problem. I want to access a specific page which consists of two editable textfields and some non important elements, read all the textfields out into a Java programm, which is designated to filter the keywords out and generate a string. Then I would like to post that string back into one of those textfields if possible, to post my string to the site. Problem is I do not own the site and the page I want to access is password secured(I need to login), which I of course know. Furthermore, I´m just not familiar with anything but Java, otherwise I would write the filter in a different language.

First i tried to use the URL class from Java reading the source code, searching that code for the content of both textfields and then filter it. But I could not connect to the Page, due to the password protection. After that I tried to find a workaround, I wanted to write a Mozilla Firefox addon, which gets the source code via "document.documentElement.innerHTML", then gives that to my Java programm or write it in a temporary file to access for my programm. But I couldnt find a command to do either.

So I would need a solution to either send the password to access the particular page, and or to get the content of the Textfields in another way, getting the source code of the page would be fine. And last I would need a smooth way to post my filtered String to the website.

Thanks in advance, I hope you understand my problem and got a solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    String header;
    String textbox;
    String shopname;

    try {
        url = new URL("TestURL");
        is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line.contains("Gib hier den Titel an")){//After this line follows the textbox, works just as the first test.
                line = br.readLine();
                header=line;
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
         mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }
    }
    System.out.println(filterH(header));
    System.out.println(filterT(textbox));//to be implemented.
}

// Simple Addon still
exports.main = function() {};
require("widget").Widget({
id: "widgetID1",
label: "My Mozilla Widget", //to be changed
contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico" // To be changed
 onClick: function(event) {
    var x= document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  //do Filter and Stuff
}
});
```

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try embedding the credentials in the URL as:

`http://username:password@www.example.com/page.html`

Comment: Good try :) but it doesnt work to log in that way, neither via code nor with typing it into the browser. Maybe using the Cookie or such?

Comment: Ah, so it requires you to log in? Then you can either access several URLs, simulating the log in process, which I think will work, or get a valid cookie and provide that. I'm not sure how to offhand, though.

Comment: And how would I simulate a log in process ? The loginpage consists of a Field for the username, the password and obvious a submit button. The embedding method didn´t work for that. I guess it would be nice to log in once per session, not every time again.

Comment: When that submit button is clicked, it probably sends the username and password back to the server with an HTTP POST. You could observe what happens in Fiddler or TamperData, and then duplicate it from Java. You can probably also determine what happens by examining the source of the page -- are the username and password in a form element? What is the action of that form?

Comment: Sorry for the late "approved/thanks for answer" I´m new to Stackoverflow : )